# Extract a custom action's dll from msi-file

Tags: dll, windows-installer, custom-action

How to extract managed custom action's dll from msi-file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Orca tool, available in Windows SDK. Open the MSI with Orca and go to Binary table. Double click the "Data" column corespondent for the resource used by our custom action. You will get a modal dialog with options to save the content of the column, or to overwrite it.

Comment: I tried that, but it seems the extracted file is not the original assembly. Do I have to do another step?

Comment: No, that should be it. What do you mean it is not the original assembly? Share more details or maybe post another question and link it to this one

Comment: I created a [new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70850262/how-to-get-the-code-of-a-custom-action-in-a-msi) question.